# Accessing keys when looping over a list of dicts in Ansible

Tags: ansible, yaml

Ansible's documentation on YAML syntax has this example:

```
# Employee records
-  martin:
    name: Martin D'vloper
    job: Developer
    skills:
      - python
      - perl
      - pascal
-  tabitha:
    name: Tabitha Bitumen
    job: Developer
    skills:
      - lisp
      - fortran
      - erlang
```

if I was looping over this data structure with [loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html) how would I access the values 'tabitha' and 'martin' only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the list is stored under `my_list` name:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.keys() | first }}"
  loop: "{{ my_list }}"
```

or with JMESPath:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ my_list | json_query('[].keys(@)') | flatten }}"
```